# How to disable automount for specific, internal partitions on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, mount, automount

I have an iMac on which I set up a Windows 7 on a separate partition of main main drive (an SSD) with Bootcamp. After installing the Bootcamp drivers, Windows is abled to read HFS+ file systems (even though reading only). I have a second drive (an ordinary hard disk drive). The OS X partition as well as the other disk get mounted by Windows automatically on startup as internal (non-removable) disks, like they are.

Because of the purpose of this Windows installation, I do not need and also want to prevent access to these other partitions (for security reasons). Is there a smooth way of doing so? Else than, in example, to run a script on login which unmounts these drives again?

I know how easy this would be on Linux, but I am stalled with Windows. Until now I just found out how to disable automatic mounting of drives on Windows globally, but not how to make it based on partitions. That is the way I mean it: Windows should not even touch them on startup, just be aware they are there and should be left in peace.

Comment: Maybe hiding is enough for the file system to not access it: [Using Group Policy Objects to hide specified drives](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289/en-us) (Haven't tested it, so no full answer from me)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable automatic startup of Apple HFS driver ("AppleHFS") so HFS partitions (drives) will not appear in Windows.

I recommend using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) for that.

I'd rather recommend create a FAT32 partion, then create encrypted container with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (100GB for example), format it as FAT32 and be able to access it on both mac and Windows (after entering the password).